# Matching element heights

Tags: javascript, css, menu, height

I have a menu on the left side of a slider.  The slider's height is in direct correlation to the size of the image file that it loads.  I want the menu's parent element to be at an equal height to the slider at all time.

I tried to code this with CSS and I looked around on here and realized that doing it with CSS is impossible.  So, I tried to code it with Java, but it isn't right.

Any help with this would be amazing!

--Update--

This part is an edit.  I tried a few of the suggestions, however they are not working.  The slider changes height as it responds to the width of the screen.  So, when I drag it out, it will change and the menu is left shorter than the slider.  If I max-height the slider, the width will not display at 100% of the 60% allowance.

I believe what I need is a snippet of jquery that:
- grabs the nav element
- detects the height of the .Slider
- makes the nav element the same height as the .Slider element.

I have tried the js code below, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the code:

```js
  window.jQuery( function() {
    window.jQuery('nav').height(window.jQuery('.Slider').height ())
  });
```

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  background: lightgreen;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.3333%;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.Slider {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Item 1
      </li>
      <li>
        Item 2
      </li>
      <li>
        Item 3
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="Slider">
    Pics are here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a clearfix, or I don't understand the question. Try this:

```
.theParent:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not only this is possible with CSS, there are thousands of ways to do this. This is just one of those:

```
.wrapper {
    background: lightgreen;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
}
nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.Slider {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.Slider img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.clear {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    float:none;
}
```

and some tiny changes in your HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="Slider">
        <img src="http://www.open.edu/openlearn/sites/www.open.edu.openlearn/files/design-nutshell-homepage.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

(pay attention to that `.clear` div, which is the main reason why you probably had problems)

IN this case, since I notices you used percentages, I also added responsive behaviors.

[fiddle to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/wmpLdxbo/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little Jquery to solve this situation.

Just before the  tag, you can add:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('nav').css('height','100%');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!!!! So friggin' happy right now!!

```
var maxHeight = 400;

  $("div").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
  });

$("div").height(maxHeight);
```